# Cannot use instance member 'idnum' within property initializer;

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to use the instance variable but encounters some problem, this movieDetail is the destination of a navigationlink and idnum is get from there.

```
struct movieDetail: View {
    
    var idnum:Int
    var mvde = testMv(idStr: String(idnum))
     var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView{
            
            VStack{
                ForEach(mvde.todos){info in
                    Text(info.overview)
                    
                }
                }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
         
                    }
       
    }
}

struct movieDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            movieDetail(idnum:24428)
        }
       
    }
}
```

In this movieDetail view, I want to use `idnum` as a parameter to create a `testMv` object, while I get the info : `Cannot use instance member 'idnum' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`, I tried to place the `var mvde = testMv(idStr: String(idnum))` into the body part but get `Variable 'mvde' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant`.

Comment: You need to create your own custom initialiser rather than using the synthesised one. Also by convention structs should have capital letters, so it should be `MovieDetail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follows

```
struct movieDetail: View {
    
    var idnum:Int
    var mvde: testMv

    init(idnum: Int) {
        self.idnum = idnum
        self.mvde = testMv(idStr: String(idnum))
    }

   ...
}
```